# Input element not initializing correctly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

My Android app contains an activity with multiple tabs implemented with ViewPager and TabLayout elements. In one of these tabs, there is a form which allows a user to fill in some details and then save those details.

In `onCreateView`, I fetch the `TextInputEditText` elements and initialize them.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);

    usernameInput = (TextInputEditText) view.findViewById(R.id.username_input);
    usernameInput.setText("Test username"); // This works

    // Repeat for other TextInputEditTexts

    return view;
}
```

However when clicking the Save button (implemented with a FAB), the `save()` method shows that `TextInputEditText` elements are null. Why is this happening?

```
public void save() {
    String username = usernameInput.getText().toString();
    // Crash - usernameInput NullException error
}
```

Another one of the tabs in this same activity offers a very similar UI and logic (ie. another form and 'save' button), and yet it all works correctly there.

Logcat shows the following error - is this related in any way?

```
moveToState: Fragment state for MyFragment not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
```

Comment: which support library you are using?

Comment: @Divyesh v4:23.4.0

Comment: I read about it and other says it is just warning and google updated library to solve that issue. Try to use v 24 support library.

Comment: @Divyesh Updated to v25 and still getting the same error

Comment: try to move your code  usernameInput = (TextInputEditText) view.findViewById(R.id.username_input);
    usernameInput.setText("Test username"); // This works

    // Repeat for other TextInputEditTexts
    inside of OnViewCreated() method.